# JavaScript: What's the callee?

Tags: javascript

Also, what do its methods *call* and *apply* mean and how to use all that stuff?

Comment: Unless you add some details, context, and preferably some code, your question will get closed. For example: how did you come up with the question? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Caller = the one calling; callee = the one being called.

Comment: Voted to close. You may want to read the FAQ, Gregori: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Voted to close. Questions as general as this should be more elaborate. Ask many detailed questions and/or provide example situations. Also - not be trivial to find with google. [you can edit your question and write more]

Answer (score 4):

The *caller* is the function that calls another function.

The *callee* is the function that is called. So inside a function, [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee) always refers to the function itself.

---

This is analogous to terms in other areas, e.g. Trainer <-> Trainee.

Answer (score 3):

[`apply()` and `call()`.](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Noun

**callee** (plural callees)

1. The person who is called by the caller (on the telephone).
2. (computing) A function called by another.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply